# Indent Document, Ignore problems

Tags: php, html, css, tidy

I want to just reindent a html + php + javascript spaghetti document. The document may have broken HTML but I don't want it to fix it or remove the broken tags. I just want to reindent it correctly so its readable.

The reason is that I a 2k html document with php and javascript spaghetti code all over the place; and it just "works". The thing is, it's un-indented the spacing is a mess and it's just unreadable. So for me to be able to "fix" this mess I need to understand how it works...

`Tidy` seems to be breaking the document; no idea why. So I'm looking for an alternative here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing this in vim. Open the document with `vim ./file` then press `ggVG=`, then `:wq`. Make sure you have a backup.

Or you might try with Eclipse. Open the file and go to Source > Format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you need, but Dreamweaver has a nice command called "Apply source formatting" under the "comments" tab..